# explain like I'm five: Why are dojo scripts recommended to be written in <body>?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I referred the [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/) but didn't quite understand it. While working on Javascript with jQuery, I always wrote scripts in the `<head>`. So why should I write dojo scripts in `<body>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not solely Dojo. Loading JavaScript files in your head, means that the entire page is blocked while the `<head>` is being loaded. Considering the fact that most browsers only support up to 2 simultaneous downloads it means you might be staring at a blank page for a while until the scripts are finished loading.

More can be found at [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) from Yahoo.

Answer (score 1):

The [Hello Dojo!](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/hello_dojo/) tutorial says,

> We have also placed the `<script>` block in the body of the HTML document. We could place it in the header and things would have worked the same, but when you end up in a situation where your application loads a lot of code, having the `<script>` blocks in the header can [keep the page from rendering](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/27/loading-scripts-without-blocking/) while [they are being loaded](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=top). This adds to the user perception of the application "being slow" and can degrade the user experience, so we will generally be demonstrating loading Dojo at the end of the body of the document.

Putting it in the body instead of the head means that the browser can begin to render the page before the script has finished loading: which makes the page-load seem faster.

Comment: Not to forget, even jQuery does it: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Answer (score 1):

You also can write your Javascript in a seperate Js-File and just link it in the header
like :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="myJavascriptInside.js"></script>
```

No mixin between Html and Javascript. It's also mentioned in Dimitris link

[Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)

Here's a snippet from it:

> Using external files in the real world generally produces faster pages because the JavaScript and CSS files are cached by the browser. JavaScript and CSS that are inlined in HTML documents get downloaded every time the HTML document is requested. This reduces the number of HTTP requests that are needed, but increases the size of the HTML document. On the other hand, if the JavaScript and CSS are in external files cached by the browser, the size of the HTML document is reduced without increasing the number of HTTP requests.

This is the way we do it and it works great.

Regards, Miriam